How to abspath a bazel --action_env=CPATH=../python3.10/Include
I'm using bazel 6.5.0-7 and want to specify common --action_env=CPATH=../python3.10/Include in .bazelrc (the python3.10/ is our built-in-bazel python distribution, and it's specified as a data dep of the target in question).
Unfortunately, the third party python library that needs to consume CPATH cannot handle a relative path (it changes directory to a tempdir before invoking gcc), and only works if I also os.environ["CPATH"] = os.path.abspath(os.environ["CPATH"]) in the code prior to invoking the library.  I don't want to force every consumer of this library to have to include this boilerplate.
I cannot hardcode the path, as it changes based on the target_name.runfiles, bazel run vs. test, fastbuild vs. opt, etc.  My rules_python is old enough that I cannot patch the third party library wheel.  I intend to file an issue with the third party library, but do not want to wait for a new release to land.
How can I tell bazel to make the relative path be absolute (but late enough to still be specified correctly)?
